# How to efficiently import data from files containing a mix of numbers and strings into a Matlab cell array?

Tags: matlab, parsing, import

I have about thirty **text files** of varying dimensions in which the average is **2050x1450**. As the figure shows, the first two rows are of type **char** indicating the number of profile and the recording time respectively. the remaining rows are values of type **double**.

```
       #1        #2       #3...........#10      #1       #2       #3......
Time 21:22:10 21:23:56 21:24:07.... 06:19:11 06:21:00 06:21:23 06:23:11......
15    0.00     0.00      0.00   ....  0.00      0.00     0.00    0.00......
30   -6.09    1200.44   32.08   .... -0.17     9.87    -44.65   768.12......
.      .         .        .     .....           .         .         .........
.      .         .        .     .....           .         .         .........
.      .         .        .     .....           .         .         .........
2050  76.009   32.98   -5.91    ..... 79.15    15.54    -87.60  -10.74 ......
```

with this structure, i found difficulties to assigh the content of those files into a cell array under matlab since the command '**dlmread**' is conceived only for numeric data. my question is the following:
how can I assigh effeciently the content of those files into the cell array?

I tested it with **importdata** command matlab:

```
PathName = uigetdir;
d = dir(fullfile(PathName,'*.txt'));
    for i = 1:numel(d)
    A(i) = importdata(fullfile(PathName, d(i).name),'\t');
end
```

When i execute it,I had three flow (data, text data, colheaders). My first line is all stored in a single box **A(1,1).textdata{1,1}**. **A(1,1).textdata{1,2}**,...,**A(1,1).textdata{1,1450}** are completely empty,contrary to what I get with the second row.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
A(i) = importdata(filename,' ',2)
```

which will give you all of the doubles in a matrix and the times in a cell array.

The first line ends up as one string. You can split that out into a matrix like so:

```
headerStr = strsplit(A(i).textdata{1})
```

`strsplit` is a new function in Matlab 2013. In older versions of Matlab, this should work:

```
headerStr = textscan(A(i).textdata{1},'%s')
```

You can then convert these matrices to cell arrays using `num2cell`

```
headerCells = num2cell(headerStr{1})
```

which will return a cell array with one string per cell

Now you have your first line of '#1' etc in `headerCells`, your 2nd line of times in `A(i).textdata{2}`, and all of your numbers in `A(i).data`

You can combine this into one big cell array thusly:

```
alldata = [[cell(1) headerCells']; A(i).textdata(2,:); num2cell(A(i).data)]
```

Comment: how can we have the first two lines in a cell array? my problem with the first line

Comment: @user3137771, use strsplit and num2cell. I updated the answer for you.

Comment: This gives me an error message :

??? Undefined function or method 'strsplit' for input
arguments of type 'char'. But why in A(1,1).textdata{1,2},...,A(1,1).textdata{1,1450} are completely empty?

Comment: strsplit appears to be a new function in Matlab 2013. In older versions, you can use textscan

Comment: when I use:                                 textscan(A(1).textdata{1},'%s'), ans = {1449x1 cell}                 but i find normally ans = {1x1 cell} (or #1)

Comment: textscan will give you a cell array with one cell in it, which contains a 1449x1 matrix of your strings. So you can get any individual string as ans{1}(n). If you want a cell array with one value per cell, use num2cell(ans{1}).

Comment: I do not know whether past treatment with 'dlmread is false? if the command 'textscan is recommended, how will the code to assign any data. Can you see my discription here : http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/144289-how-to-import-data-from-files-containing-a-mix-of-numbers-and-strings-into-a-matlab-cell-array

Comment: You can put everything into one cell array like so: [[cell(1) headerCells']; A(1).textdata(2,:); num2cell(A(i).data)]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i don't know if that's exactly:                    PathName = uigetdir;
    d = dir(fullfile(PathName,'*.txt'));
    for i = 1:numel(d)
    
    A(i) = importdata(fullfile(PathName, d(i).name),'\t');
    headerStr = textscan(A(i).textdata{1},'%s');
    headerCells = num2cell(headerStr{1});
    alldata(i) = [[cell(i) headerCells']; A(i).textdata(2,:); num2cell(A(i).data)];
    
end

Comment: Thanks for your answer,the program works well but very long and instead of (# N), I find ('# N'). In addition to alldata a variable (i) to import thirty files gives me error.

Comment: i combined all into one big cell array. When, I associate a variable (i) for alldata on within the for loop to assign thirty files, it gives me an error message: In an assignment A (:) = B, the number of elements in A and B 
must be the same.

Comment: I initialized alldata: alldata=cell(1,30), and I introduced alldata to the inside of the for loop like this: alldata{i} = [[cell(1) headerCells']; A(i).textdata(2,:); num2cell(A(i).data)]; i think works well, but its very long

Comment: Do you mean by "it's very long" that it is slow? You can use Matlab's tic and toc functions to look for inefficiencies in your code. I don't know of a faster way to read a file than importdata.

Comment: yes it's very slowly,(3 files for 161.678498 s), i have cpu i5.